# Отслеживание системных вызовов на C и Assembler

Tags: c, ассемблер

Мне интересно есть ли возможность, отслеживать системные вызовы. Например: какая-то программа показывает MessageBox для этого делает вызов системной функции. Мне нужно отследить это событие. При этом нужно мониторить не какую то конкретную программу а все запущенные.

Comment: 1. Да... есть. Антивирусы на этом часто живут. Написание такой программы довольно сложное дело. 2. С и Ассемблер  - это инструмент, который генерирует исполнимый код. Если что-то можно написать на С - то это же самое можно написать на ассемблере. Наоборот - невсегда, поскольку ассемблер позволяет более оптимально использовать инструкции ЦП, но в "общем случае" тоже с большей вероятностью можно.

Comment: Такая программа - дело не одного дня, поищите в интернете APISpy программу, или её аналог.

Comment: Насколько я знаю антивирусники, мониторят вызовы запуская процесс в песочнице или я не прав?

Comment: Очень спорный вопрос, без конкретики нет смысла говорить. Разные по-разному.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/infopulse/blog/140456/

Comment: Ну я имею ввиду, что антивирусники, отладчики и дизассемблеры делают все это запуская процесс в собственной песочнице или подключаясь к памяти процесса. А без этого просто мониторить вызовы всех запущенных процессов  возможно?

Comment: Конечно можно - драйвер ядра. Темные дебри... То ли KeServices - таблица АПИ (часть основных вызов ядра) то ли что-то такое, то ли int31. Но как туда получить доступ... не знаю. Правда  MessageBox проходит через ядро или нет - не помню. Если нет - прийдётся вероятнее всего всерано перехватывать dll-ки.

Comment: Уровень драйвера - KeServiceDescriptorTable - информации в поисковике много, но не перехватывал. Не могу оценить какой источник лучше.

Comment: А перехватывать и изменять результат вызова функции возможно? Например: файловый менеджер (любой) получает список файлов в определенной директории. И нужно перехватить и изменить список файлов, удалив системные файлы из списка.

Comment: Всё можно))))  Вопрос только сколько денег времени и зачем вам это. Мне кажется что вопрос стал переходит из разряда IT в разряд философии...

Comment: Я думал о реализации программы для защиты системы от детей и неопытных пользователей. Типа спрятать системные файлы и процессы.

Comment: 1. Если не ошибаюсь, начиная с Win7 все важные системные файлы защищены, и без пароля администратора - не могут быть удалены. Не нужно просто работать из-по админа:) 2. Реализация такой программы у вас займет не один не два дня. Несколько месяцев наверно. Немного зависит от опыта написания такого рода программ. Как вариант - перехватите  KeServiceDescriptorTable - и станьте властелином файловой системы. За сколько времени получится - не могу сказать:)